# How can I use DisplayModeProvider in ASP.NET MVC 3 to specify postfix for mobile views

Tags: iphone, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mobile

I need to do something like this

```
 DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode("iPhone")
    {
        ContextCondition = (context => context.GetOverriddenUserAgent().IndexOf
            ("iPhone", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
    });
```

But seems it wount work in MVC 3 project.
How can I enable DefaultDisplayMode supporting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display modes are an ASP.NET MVC 4 feature. If you want to get this behaviour then you either need to upgrade to ASP.NET MVC 4 or write a custom view engine for ASP.NET MVC 3.